# Exporting file in R using part of original file name

Tags: r, regex, csv

I am hoping to write a csv from a manipulated data frame using part of the original file name. I want to extract everything **before the underscore**, so in this case, just the 96. Nothing else. Some files contain 3 numbers, some are 2, but all are before the underscore.

```
file <- "96_2016-01-01~2016-08-08.xlsx"
x <- read.table(file, as.is=T)

#extracting csv using full file name, but want to just use 96
write.csv <- (x$All, paste(file,".csv"), row.names=FALSE)
```

**current file name**: 96_2016-01-01~2016-08-08.xlsx.csv

**desired file name**: 96.csv

Is there some way to use regex or gsub? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `_` followed by other characters (`.*`) and replace it with `.csv`

```
sub("_.*", ".csv", file)
#[1] "96.csv"
```

---

If we need to be more specific, match one or more numbers (`\\d+`) at the start (`^`) of the string, capture as a group (`(...)`) followed by `_` and other characters (`.*`), replace by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group followed by `.csv`

```
sub("^(\\d+)_.*", "\\1.csv", file)
#[1] "96.csv"
```

Comment: Perfection. That was quick and does exactly what I wanted. Will accept answer once stack overflow lets me!

Comment: Full code = write.csv(x$All, paste(sub("_.*", ".csv", file)), row.names=F)